# Can you define typingStart to a specific channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to get my discord bot to send this message only if the user starts typing in the defined channel. I don't get errors the bot just doesn't send a message. What am I doing wrong?

```
bot.on("typingStart", (message , channel) => {

const bot_channel =  "812180709401247658"

   if (channel.id === bot_channel.id) {
       message.send('wrong channel');
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

bot_channel is a string, so the value of bot_channel.id is undefined, which doesn't equal channel.id.